# Java documentlistener - program stop working after input

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, illegalstateexception, documentlistener

Hi I have problem with my documentlistener. 
Program stop working after I insert value into textfield. This program should XOR 1st row of textfields with 2nd row of textfields and put result into 3rd row of textfields

```
package opa.beta1;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TextFieldEvent {

    JTextField arrayIV[] = new JTextField[8];
    JTextField plaintextArray[] = new JTextField[8];
    JTextField ciphertextArray[] = new JTextField[8];
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("OPA");
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

    public void setJPanel(JTextField array[], JPanel container, String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            array[i] = new JTextField(s, 4);
            array[i].getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    setCiphertext();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    setCiphertext();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    setCiphertext();
                }
            });
            container.add(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public String setXORText(JTextField textfield1, JTextField textfield2) {
        String okno1, okno2;
        okno1 = textfield1.getText();
        okno2 = textfield2.getText();
        if (okno1.equals("")) {
            return okno2;
        }
        BigInteger pom1 = new BigInteger(okno1, 16);
        if (okno2.equals("")) {
            return okno1;
        }
        BigInteger pom2 = new BigInteger(okno2, 16);
        BigInteger res = pom1.xor(pom2);
        String s = res.toString(16);
        return s;
    }

    public String setXORText(JTextField pole1[], JTextField pole2[], int i) {

        String okno1 = pole1[i].getText();
        String okno2 = pole2[i].getText();
        if (okno1.equals("")) {
            return pole2[i].getText();
        }
        BigInteger pom1 = new BigInteger(okno1, 16);
        if (okno2.equals("")) {
            return pole1[i].getText();
        }
        BigInteger pom2 = new BigInteger(okno2, 16);
        BigInteger res = pom1.xor(pom2);
        String s = res.toString(16);
        return s;
    }

    public void setCiphertext() {
        //textfield3.setText(setXORText(textfield1, textfield2));
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            ciphertextArray[i].setText(setXORText(arrayIV, plaintextArray, i));
        }
    }

    public TextFieldEvent() {
        setJPanel(arrayIV, panel1, "1a");
        setJPanel(plaintextArray, panel2, "1b");
        setJPanel(ciphertextArray, panel3, "1");

        frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(675, 275);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TextFieldEvent();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(AbstractDocument.java:1338) at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:659) at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1718) at opa.beta1.TextFieldEvent.setCiphertext(TextFieldEvent.java:82) at opa.beta1.TextFieldEvent$1.removeUpdate(TextFieldEvent.java:33)
```

Comment: "Program stop working" - did it throw any exception? What do you mean by "stop working"?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(AbstractDocument.java:1338)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:659)
 at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1718)
 at opa.beta1.TextFieldEvent.setCiphertext(TextFieldEvent.java:82)
 at opa.beta1.TextFieldEvent$1.removeUpdate(TextFieldEvent.java:33)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
setJPanel(ciphertextArray, panel3, "1");
```

also adds a `DocumentListener` to every element of the `ciphertextArray` `TextField`. So every time the value of one of your cipher text `TextField`s changes, the method `setCipherText()` is invoked.

This leads to the following sequence:

1. You enter a new value in one of the `TextField`s of `arrayIV` or `plainTextArray`
2. `setCipherText()` is invoked
3. `setCipherText()` changes the value of a cipher text `TextField`
4. `setCipherText()` is again invoked (explanation above). Go back to 2.

Thats why you get the `IllegalStateException`.

So the solution is to do NOT add a `DocumentListener` to the `TextFields` in your `ciphertextArray`.

Solution could be implemented as follows:

```
public void setJPanel(JTextField array[], JPanel container, String s, boolean docListener) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        array[i] = new JTextField(s, 4);
        if (docListener) {
            array[i].getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    setCiphertext();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    setCiphertext();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    setCiphertext();
                }
            });
        }
        container.add(array[i]);
    }
}

[...]

    setJPanel(arrayIV, panel1, "1a", true);
    setJPanel(plaintextArray, panel2, "1b", true);
    setJPanel(ciphertextArray, panel3, "1", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `setCiphertext();` in your DocumentListener in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`